# How do I pass in multiple self-signed certificates in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Would I absolutely have to do certificate chaining? I've been at this problem for the last 2 days, but haven't been able to figure it out.

My company uses an internal self-signed certificate to verify log-in signatures. Once in, I am building a service that I am restricting to certain users. This call would be passed on to the DB, so we want to make sure it comes from a verified source, i.e. my own self-signed certificate. I have the certificate authority, but I need to validate it at a specific path. Here is where I'm listening for the default company cert:

```
   var httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);
   httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

The default certificates are already being passed through httpsOptions. I cannot piggy-back my own certificates there as well.
Once this is done, I thought about how I could pass in my own cert.

```
router.post('/subpath', async function(req, res) {
    console.log("In subpath");

    const cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate();

    if(req.client.authorized) {
        res.send(`Hello ${cert.subject.CN}, your certificate was issued by ${cert.issuer.CN}`)
    } 
    else if(cert.subject) {
        res.status(403).send(`Sorry, ${cert.subject.CN}, certificates issued by ${cert.issuer.CN} are not welcome here`);
    }
    else {
        res.status(401).send(`Sorry, pls send cert`);
    }

    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress + ' ' +
                req.method + ' ' +
                req.url
                );

    const request = req.body;

    // some response here
    res.json(...);
});

module.exports = router;
```

One thing I tried but didn't work was (in index.js):

```
httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT)
        .on('listening', function() {
            CHILD = 'yes';
            PORT = this.address().port;
            NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = '/pathToCertificate/ca-crt.pem';
        });
```

This particular call in coming in from a cURL post call. How can I validate the incoming certificate? Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Update: I also tried passing in a callback function in the router to validate the certificate through some middleware, but ran into the same problem, i.e. how can I receive the certificate and validate it?

Comment: Do you want to pass in client certificate or server certificate?

Comment: Server certificate, along with client key and client certificate to validate the identity of the client.